# How to get my "if else" statements to work properly in this Node file using Inquirer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, inquirer

I'm trying to get some code to have a certain message to appear on the screen depending on what answer they give on a question. This is a node application that is using the Inquirer package and every-time that I run the node application, it comes back with "undefined".

```
{
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "channels",
        message: "Which of these TV channels would you watch?!",
        choices: ["Investigation Discovery", "CNN", "Fox News", "TLC"]
    }
]).then(function (responses) {
    for(let i = 0; i < responses.channels; i++) {
        if (responses.channels === 0) {
            console.log("You are probably smart");
        }`enter code here`
        else if (responses.channels === 1) {
            console.log("You are probably well informed");
        }
        else if (responses.channels === 2) {
            console.log("You are probably not very well informed");
        }
        else {
            console.log("You are probably an idiot");
        }
    }
```

As stated before, it is supposed to return a message in the console depending on what choice was chosen, but it only comes back with "undefined".

Comment: What does an example `response` look like?

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(responses)`?

Comment: The output is: Which of these TV channels would you watch?! Investigation Discovery
{ channels: [ 0 ] }

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use the wrong type. Checkbox allow to select multiple response.

For your use case, you should use `list` or `rawlist` and an array of object the choices, to have a different value between what is displayed and what you want to use after.

So, something like that should be what you excpeted:

```js
const inquirer = require("inquirer");


inquirer
  .prompt([
    {
        type: "list",
        name: "channels",
        message: "Which of these TV channels would you watch?!",
        choices: [{ name: "Investigation Discovery", value: 0 }, { name: "CNN", value: 1 }, { name: "Fox News", value: 2}, { name: "TLC", value: 3}]
    }
  ])
  .then((responses) => {
        if (responses.channels === 0) {
            console.log("You are probably smart");
        }
        else if (responses.channels === 1) {
            console.log("You are probably well informed");
        }
        else if (responses.channels === 2) {
            console.log("You are probably not very well informed");
        }
        else {
            console.log("You are probably an idiot");
        }
});
```

Comment: On which operating system are you ? I have updated the previous message to remove the for loop. Try with this new sample.

Comment: Im using macOS Mojave. I did get a different response this time except it would only print "You are probably an idiot" no matter what choice I made

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to solve it myself. Here is what I needed to do:

```
    if (responses.channels = 1) {
        console.log("You are probably smart");
    }
    else if (responses.channels = 2) {
        console.log("You are probably well informed");
    }
    else if (responses.channels = 3) {
        console.log("You are probably not very well informed");
    }
    else {
        console.log("You are probably an idiot");
    }
```

Comment: Try choosing TLC for example

Comment: I don't think this will work as you intend it to. The first conditional will always evaluate to true, since you're making an assignment in the conditional (`responses.channels = 1`)